# how to get text with Selenium in the python from <span class> if appears for few seconds?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, html-table, webdriverwait

I have a question related to getting a text from span class with Selenium in the Python script.
I've already checked many variants to get text, but still no luck.
The main reason - mentioned element appears on the page for several seconds and disappears and I need to get "Latest" text from that element.

Here is element, which appears for few seconds:

```
 </style><div class="PNs8Z result_1613936507015"><span class="genericPhrase" data-role="final_result">Latest</span></div></div></div></div>
```

I've already tried several approaches, which I found in the Selenium documentation and in the Internet:

```
wait.until(presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.final_result")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(@class,'final_result')]"))
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.final_result")))
```

But, still no luck. I found solutions when the element permanently on the page and doesn't disappear, but that approach hasn't worked yet for me.

Maybe somebody has already faced such an issue and has a ready solution for my case?

Thanks in advance.
Ihor

Comment: Did you find a solution in answers?

Answer (score 1):

To search xpath of such dynamic elements use DOM break points:

[image]

And select break on subtree modification. Now all changes will break and pause the webpage rendering

[image]

Click resume execution or press f8 till your span gets displayed

Answer (score 0):

To get the value `Latest` which is inside `span` tag use following `xpath`

Try with `.text`

```
print(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//span[@class='genericPhrase' and @data-role='final_result']"))).text)
```

Or Try with `.get_attribute("textContent")`

```
print(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//span[@class='genericPhrase' and @data-role='final_result']"))).get_attribute("textContent"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are incorrectly identifying your locator.
Try

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".genericPhrase").text
```

To wait for visibility use:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=20)           
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((SelectBy.CSS_SELECTOR, ".genericPhrase")))
```